# MongoDB - I can't remove or unset an embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This seems like it should be simple.  I have a collection with an embedded document.  I simply want to use the mongodb shell to remove every embedded document for that key name (links), but nothing I've tried has worked.  I've also tried specifying individual _id's but that doesn't work either.  The id's in these collections are not standard mongo object id's

MongoDB version is 2.4.8.

I started with this, but it had no effect:

```
db.products.update({}, { $unset: { links: 1 } }, { multi: true} );
```

All the links attributes are unchanged.

Here's a sample document (I'm not showing other fields, but they exist);

```
{ "_id" : "54227cf1-096b-4715-ae52-c2c9df3e8b6a", "links" : { "_id" : "9793093c-2422-48f5-9961-ca85e3896e98", "url" : "http://www.yahoo.com", "merchant" : "eae1ec9d-bf04-471d-82c9-c6b235d67112", "expires" : "07/49/2016", "created_at" : ISODate("2014-01-28T02:50:05.976Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-01-28T02:50:05.976Z") } }
```

Here's one of the many variations I've tried:

```
> db.product.update({_id: "54227cf1-096b-4715-ae52-c2c9df3e8b6a"}, { $unset: {links:  ""}});
```

> db.runCommand({getLastError: 1})
>   {
>       "updatedExisting" : false,
>       "n" : 0,
>       "connectionId" : 1,
>       "err" : null,
>       "ok" : 1
>   }

How about just setting it?

```
> db.product.update({_id: "54227cf1-096b-4715-ae52-c2c9df3e8b6a"}, { $set: {links:  ""}});
```

> db.runCommand({getLastError: 1})
>   {
>       "updatedExisting" : false,
>       "n" : 0,
>       "connectionId" : 1,
>       "err" : null,
>       "ok" : 1
>   }

#### Update and conclusion

After verifying with others that the syntax was correct and *should* have worked, I started looking at the environment (vagrants/virtualbox) as a possible issue.  While this has associated dangers with it ([rtfm!)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) none of which are a concern for my development database, I ended up running [db.repairDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) as well as rebooting my workstation.  Things began to work again after this, but I hesitate to entirely rule out pebkac.

Comment: I just tried it using your sample data and it worked without issue.

Comment: @Pawel: only, with my server it isn't removed.  This must be a problem with our environment.  We're running inside virtualbox environments using vagrant, and I'm going to guess that it's something related to that.

Comment: @WiredPrarie:  thanks for letting me know.  I thought that should work but it doesn't for my environment.

Comment: @gview Does `find({_id:"54227cf1-096b-4715-ae52-c2c9df3e8b6a"})` find the object? The last error you get back is consistent with update that didn't actually find anything for the query.

Comment: If you do exactly the steps above (not with extra data), it doesn't work? Look for the document using `find` as suggested by @PawelVeselov.

Comment: @PawelVeselov. Yes, the find worked as expected.  I should also say that what I originally was doing was using {} to match all, which didn't work.  You both helped me verify that there wasn't a problem with my syntax.  I shutdown all my vm's and rebooted, and did a db.repairDatabase() and after that the queries began to work.  There's nothing I can replicate but I put it in my notes in case I encounter something like this again.